# How to use a backslash in quotes (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `head, sep, tail = email.partition('\')` but having trouble escaping the backslash properly.  What is the proper way to get a partition at the `\` using this line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By escaping the backslash.

```
'\\'
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, that's what I was looking for.  For some reason I'm still getting this result though: `'greg@searchedandfound.com.au\n'`.. How is this possible?

Comment: That's not a backslash, that's a newline.